# MySQL natural search and like search

Tags: mysql, mvc, scala, search

I have written two queries for searching, but I want to simplify them as it seems needed.

```
def searching(term: String): List[String] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      var list = List[String]()
      val pinfo = SQL("SELECT body FROM tableName WHERE body like {term} limit 0,14 ").on("term" -> ("%" + term + "%"))()
      pinfo.map {
        row =>
          list ::= row[String]("body")
      }
      val res = SQL("SELECT body FROM tableName WHERE MATCH (body) AGAINST ({term} IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 0,14 ").on("term" -> term)()
      res.map {
        row =>
          list ::= row[String]("body")
      }
      return list.distinct
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the two queries don't depend on each other,
and they both return the same column,
it seems you can `UNION` them.

I cannot test this, but it seems this should work:

```
  def searching(term: String): List[String] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      val result = SQL(
        "SELECT body FROM tableName WHERE body like {liketerm} limit 0,14 " +
        "UNION " +
        "SELECT body FROM tableName WHERE " +
        "MATCH (body) AGAINST ({term} IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 0,14 ").on(
          "liketerm" -> ("%" + term + "%"),
          "term" -> term
        )()
      result.map(row => row[String]("body")).distinct
    }
  }
```

Not only this is simpler,
running one query instead of two is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Before simplifying your program, you should consider its meaningfulness: you use two queries with `limit` but without any `order by` clause: since in SQL the order of the result is not specified *unless* an `order by` clause is present, every time you call the function you could get a different (random) set of tuples.